# When AWS free tier is going to expire?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I started free tier some time ago, but then abandoned it. I want to restore usage of AWS, but I'm not sure for how long I can use it for free.

In billing it says I'm under free tier, but I couldn't find when it's going to expire. How can I figure this out?

I know it lasts 12 month in general. I want to know when MY 12 months period is going to expire.

Comment: https://www.krunalparmar.com/Blog

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is one year as of now. After one year, you will still get certain services for free.

Read more about it here. https://aws.amazon.com/free/

To get to know when your 12 month period started.

1. Login as a user with access to billing information. (root user / IAM with appropriate access)
2. Go to billings from top right drop down.
3. Click "Bills" on the left. Find the oldest bill in the list of months by date. Your free tier will expire 1 year after that date.

Alternately :

Try to find welcome email from AWS in your mailbox.

Comment: Right, but how long before MY one year is going to expire?

Comment: interesting.. I used my billing information to assess that. Let me get you exact steps.

Comment: Sign in as a user who has access to the billing and cost area of the account.  (Possibly the root user, but could be Iam user if you have granted them access).  Click on your name in the top right, and choose "Billing and Cost Management". Click "Bills" on the left.  Find the oldest bill in the list of months by date. Your free tier will expire 1 year after that date.

Comment: Apart from what chris said. Alternately , try to find that email AWS sent you.